# My frontend is unable to connect to the backend address

Tags: javascript

"My frontend can't connect to the backend address, but I can make a POST request with curl. Here is the browser error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at (index):9 when trying to POST to [http://127.0.0.1:5000/process-data."](http://127.0.0.1:5000/process-data.%22)
Front-end code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>hello</title>
<script>
function sendData() {
    // Make sure the URL is the Flask application address, usually http://127.0.0.1:5000/process-data if it's local
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/process-data', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Hello, backend!'}),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Display the data returned from the backend on the webpage
        document.getElementById('response').innerText = data.reply;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="sendData()">Send data to backend</button>
<div id="response">The response from the backend will be displayed here.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Back-end code:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/process-data', methods=['POST'])
def process_data():
    # Retrieve the data sent from the front-end
    data = request.json
    print(data)  # Just as an example, the data might need to be processed in a real application

    # Suppose this is the response after processing
    reply = {'reply': f"Backend received your message: {data.get('message')}"}

    # Return the processed result to the front-end
    return jsonify(reply)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

This translation includes the comments within the code for clarity.

I've been trying to enable interaction between the front end and the back end to create a website.